# Multiple relationships in a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, angular, stored-procedures

I am preparing a query in which the total to be paid is added to the number of daily libraries that a student requests throughout the month.

It is worth mentioning that there are several types of libraries and what I need is to be able to associate the document payable to the game library catch of that month depending on the type of library

So, if a student requested 5 libraries in the month and 2 are morning and 3 are sports. 2 documents payable would be created and the morning document payable would be assigned to the 2 captures and the sports document to the 3 captures of the month.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pagodeludotecaalumnos (IN alumnoid, IN fecha) BEGIN
insert into cj_documentoporpagar(documentoid, subconceptoid, pagoestatusid, alumnoid, cicloid, gradoid,
mediopagoid, importe, saldo, fechalimitepago, fechacreacion, fechaprontopago, referencia, documento,
hermanos, reingreso, padreexalumno, concepto, iva)

select      17 as DocumentoId, 
            case when a.TipoId = 1 or a.tipoid = 2 then 122
                 when a.TipoId = 3                 then 235
                 when a.TipoId = 4                 then -1 end as SubConceptoId,
            1 as PagoEstatusId, b.AlumnoId, 
            5 as CicloId, b.GradoId, 1 as MedioPagoId,
            case when c.PrimerNombre like '%*%' or c.ApellidoPaterno like '%*%' or c.ApellidoMaterno like '%*%' then 40 * Count(*)  else  55 * Count(*) end as Importe, 
            case when c.PrimerNombre like '%*%' or c.ApellidoPaterno like '%*%' or c.ApellidoMaterno like '%*%' then 40 * Count(*)  else  55 * Count(*) end as Saldo,
            DATE(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(fecha), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as FechaLImitePago, now() as FechaCreacion, now() as FechaProntoPago,
            '' as Referencia, '202003L' as documento, 0 as Hermanos, 0 as Reingreso, 0 as PadreExAlumno,
            Concat('Ludoteca Marzo (',  cast(Count(*) as int), ') dia(s)') as Concepto, 0 as IVA
            /*, Concat(c.PrimerNombre, ' ', c.ApellidoPaterno, ' ', c.ApellidoMaterno) AlumnoNombre*/
from        lu_captura a
inner join  ce_alumnoporciclo b on a.alumnoporcicloid = b.alumnoporcicloid
inner join  ce_alumno c on b.alumnoid = c.alumnoid
where       date(a.Fecha) between DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(fecha) and a.TieneContrato = 0 and c.alumnoid = alumnoid
group by    a.TipoId, b.AlumnoId, b.GradoId

SET @LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

update lu_captura set DocumentoPorPagarId = @LID where Fecha  between DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(fecha)
```

Currently I have this query and the question is: How could I relate the document payable created to the corresponding type of library?

Comment: Although the question has been translated the query has not so it's practically impossible for me to help.

Answer (score 0):

### According to MySQL Stored Procedure

> I am using this syntax in stored procedure if you work in the same
>   then you can try this

```
DROP Procedure IF EXISTS pagodeludotecaalumnos;
```

> Delimitter to used to set whole procedure below it as single operationable

```
 DELIMITER $$
```

> Create procedure command

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pagodeludotecaalumnos (
   IN alumnoid int, IN fecha varchar(50), IN_action char(30)
)
```

> Case begin from here

```
BEGIN

  **-- switch case begin here**

   CASE 

       WHEN IN_action = "insert" THEN
```

> Creating entry for new record

```
         INSERT INTO cj_documentoporpagar(
            documentoid, subconceptoid,pagoestatusid, alumnoid, cicloid, 
            gradoid,mediopagoid, importe,saldo, fechalimitepago, fechacreacion, 
            fechaprontopago, referencia,documento,hermanos, reingreso, 
            padreexalumno, concepto, iva
         )
        VALUES(
              IN_documentoid, IN_subconceptoid, IN_pagoestatusid,
              IN_alumnoid,IN_cicloid,IN_gradoid, IN_mediopagoid, IN_importe,
              IN_saldo,IN_fechalimitepago, IN_fechacreacion,IN_fechaprontopago, 
              IN_referencia, IN_documento, IN_hermanos, IN_reingreso, 
              IN_padreexalumno, IN_concepto, IN_iva
        );
```

**-- Insert end here**

> For update

```
       WHEN IN_action = "update"  THEN

-- For update elements
-- I am only show you how i make stored procedure in mysql i.e.  your update statement

           UPDATE lu_captura SET DocumentoPorPagarId = @LID where Fecha  between 
            DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(fecha)
            WHERE condition(if_exists);
```

> For select statement

**-- For Select elements**
   **--  i.e. your select statement because i don't know what are you want to update, store an insert**

```
      WHEN IN_action = "select" THEN

          select      17 as DocumentoId, 
            case when a.TipoId = 1 or a.tipoid = 2 then 122
                 when a.TipoId = 3                 then 235
                 when a.TipoId = 4                 then -1 end as 
                 SubConceptoId,
                 1 as PagoEstatusId, b.AlumnoId, 
                 5 as CicloId, b.GradoId, 1 as MedioPagoId,
                 case when c.PrimerNombre like '%*%' or c.ApellidoPaterno 
                 like  '%*%' or c.ApellidoMaterno 
                 like '%*%' then 40 * Count(*)  
               else  55 * Count(*) end as Importe, 

            case 
               when c.PrimerNombre like '%*%' or c.ApellidoPaterno 
                 like '%*%' or c.ApellidoMaterno 
                 like '%*%' then 40 * Count(*)  else  55 * Count(*)
                 end as Saldo,
                 DATE(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(fecha), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as 
                 FechaLImitePago, now() as FechaCreacion, now() as 
                 FechaProntoPago, '' as Referencia, '202003L' as documento, 0 
                 as Hermanos, 0 as Reingreso, 0 as PadreExAlumno,
               Concat('Ludoteca Marzo (',  cast(Count(*) as int), ') dia(s)') 
                as Concepto, 0 as IVA
               /*, Concat(c.PrimerNombre, ' ', c.ApellidoPaterno, ' ', 
                c.ApellidoMaterno) AlumnoNombre*/

             from        lu_captura a
             inner join  ce_alumnoporciclo b on a.alumnoporcicloid = 
                         b.alumnoporcicloid
             inner join  ce_alumno c on b.alumnoid = c.alumnoid

            where      
               date(a.Fecha) between DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-01') and 
               LAST_DAY(fecha) and a.TieneContrato = 0 and c.alumnoid = 
               alumnoid group by    a.TipoId, b.AlumnoId, b.GradoId

    END CASE;
 -- switch case ends here

END;
```

> -- end of  the PROCEDURE